# Setting spaces between mdl grids

Tags: material-design-lite

I have recently learnt material design lite

I am using MDL grids in my html page to make three uniform divisions in a single row.

```
<div class = "mdl-grid" >
    <div  class = " mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"> 
          some text
    </div>
    <div  class = " mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"> 
          some another text 
    </div>
    <div  class = " mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col"> 
          more text
    </div>
</div>
```

But in second division, Instead of adding some text, I want to let the division be empty .That is only left(first div) and right(third div) divisions are populated with some text but the middle one (second div) remains empty space.
How can we do this using mdl?
PS: We can use margin property and delete the middle division.But I want to do this in MDL way.